# Inserting the first cell into a collection view causes an assertion failure

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

If I try to insert an item into a `UICollectionView` when there are 0 sections and 0 items, I get an assertion failure.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections. The number of sections contained in the collection
>   view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections
>   contained in the collection view before the update (0), plus or minus
>   the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

A classic. The problem is, I'm modifying my data source and then inserting the item directly afterwards. The showFirstCell property is checked in all of the necessary data source methods and it isn't modified anywhere else.

```
self.showFirstCell = true
self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)])
```

Wrapping this in `performBatchUpdates` changes nothing.

I would like for this item to be added in an animated fashion. I don't think I should have to first check if there are items already in place, but doing so and calling `reloadData` instead does work, but it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number of sections don't match up.

Once you have decided to enter a section to the `UICollectionView`, you should return the same number in your `numberOfSections` function as well.

What's happening right now is that you insert a cell, and it calls your `numberOfSections` function again, where you are still returning 0, and it promptly crashes.

Comment: Oh hah. You have to insert a section as well as a row. Of course, thank you very much. Answer accept in ~5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't work and gave you an error is because your `numberOfSections` is set to 0 and it didn't update yet when you add the cell.

To fix that, just create (if you don't have already) an `NSMutableArray`, and for `numberofSections`, return that `mutableArray`. Then whenever you add an object to the `collectionView`, just add an object to the `mutableArray` of sections.

Next and most important part is: Anytime you change, add, or remove something from the `collectionView`, just do a `beginUpdat` and `endUpdate`.

Answer (score -1):

> If you want to insert item from your CollectionView, you need to
>   insert that item from your data source which is in your array. In this example I inserted the item to myArray
>   then I inserted it also to myCollectionView. It's working because
>   the total number of items from your array (data source) is equal to
>   the number of items in the collectionView.

```
myArray.insert(valuetoinsert, atIndex: 0)
let path:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
myCollectionView.insertItems(at: [path as IndexPath])
```